# Application of exponential distributions

Tags: probability, exponential-function, gamma-function

The magnitudes of earthquakes in a region of North America can be modeled by an exponential
distribution with mean 2.5 (measured on the Richter scale). If 3 earthquakes occur in a given month, what is the probability that none exceed 5 on theRichter scale? 
I feel that I should be using the gamma function but I am unsure as to how?

Comment: Hint: Check out the properties of the cumulative distribution function for the exponential distribution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function